# fluent-plugin-bigquery: placeholder substring

Tags: fluentd

I have a JSON input to fluentd like this.

```
{ "dateTime": "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" }
```

I would like to store this message to Google BigQuery table `table_YYYYmmdd`.

I know I can write config like

```
<match tag>
  @type bigquery
  table table_%Y%m%d
     :
</match>
```

But the date in the JSON message is **not** today. I would like to store the record in accordance with the date in the JSON message.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self solved.

```
<filter tag>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    yyyymmdd ${record["dateTime"][0..9].gsub("-", "")}
  </record>
</filter>

<match tag>
  @type bigquery
  ignore_unknown_values true
  table table_${yyyymmdd}
     :
</match>
```

Comment: Hi ,How did you fixed the streaming issue to bigquery ? i tried your method and i am getting errors from the bigquery API .tabledata.insertAll ->  code=400 message="invalid: The destination table's partition table_name_${date} is outside the allowed bounds. You can only stream to partitions within 0 days in the past and 0 days in the future relative to the current date

Comment: @Meta_data I don't face your error without any configuration. I can insert my record into the table other than today.